# Implementing the View.IOnTouchListener interface

Tags: android, interface, xamarin, dispose, ontouchlistener

In Xamarin, I have coded a class that implements the `View.IOnTouchListener` interface.

Here is my code:

```
public class OnTouchListener : View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch (View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        return true;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose ()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    IntPtr Android.Runtime.IJavaObject.Handle {
        get {
            throw new NotImplementedException ();
        }
    }
}
```

What values do I need for the `IDisposable.Dispose` and `Android.Runtime.IJavaObject.Handle` code items, rather than the `throw new NotImplementedException ()` code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should inherit Java.Lang.Object in your OnTouchListener like this

```
public class OnTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object,  View.IOnTouchListener
```

it will implement Handle and Dispose

you should do this whenever implement any Java interface