# How to measure ImageView before creating bitmap into it?

Tags: layout, bitmap, imageview, xamarin.android, measure

My ImageView is matching screen size on x-axis and is using **remaining space on y-axis** in my layout. I want to create bitmap into this ImageView with exactly the same size as the ImageView is. How to make it please? Can it be done by some automatic setting, should I call some measure function?

I tried SetAdjustViewBounds() but it didn't work for me.

Creating Bitmap big enough (I don't like much such a memory wasting) and setting SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.Matrix) works, **but still when I'm making drawing operations on canvas, I don't know real size of area I should paint into**, both canvas and bitmap height are equal to yScreen while imgWeekView height is pretending to be 0, even though it paints whole desired area with gray color.

[image]

```
imgWeekView = new ImageView(context);
//imgWeekView.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);
imgWeekView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.Matrix);

layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,1f);
layoutParams.Height = 0;
imgWeekView.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap((int)xScreen, (int)yScreen, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
cnvWeekView = new Canvas(bitmap);
imgWeekView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
linearLayout.AddView(imgWeekView); //whole activity layout

//Test
cnvWeekView.DrawColor(new Color(128, 128, 128));
Paint paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
paint.Color = new Color(255, 255,0);
cnvWeekView.DrawCircle(50, 50, 40, paint);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a way how to measure my ImageView and here I will post my answer.

I believed that there should be much easier solution, but maybe there isn't. From this question I took most of the important data:

[How to get the width and height of an android.widget.ImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680499/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-android-widget-imageview)

Things look however a little different in my android application and I'm not experienced enough to tell why. I had to change things a little. I had to learn a bit about interfaces and this question helped too.

[Implementing the View.IOnTouchListener interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502974/implementing-the-view-iontouchlistener-interface)

Here is how I combined things. First I created class that will do the measure.

```
public class MyPredrawListener : Java.Lang.Object, ViewTreeObserver.IOnPreDrawListener
{
    ImageView imageView;
    public MyPredrawListener(ImageView img)
    {
        imageView = img;
    }
    public bool OnPreDraw()
    {
        imageView.ViewTreeObserver.RemoveOnPreDrawListener(this);
        int finalHeight = imageView.MeasuredHeight;
        int finalWidth = imageView.MeasuredWidth;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(finalWidth, finalHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);
        imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

        //Test to see result
        Canvas cnv = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.Color = new Color(255, 255, 0);
        cnv.DrawColor(new Color(128, 128, 128));
        cnv.DrawCircle(finalWidth-50, finalHeight-50, 50, paint);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And in code where I create my imageView I set the listener like this.

```
imgWeekView = new ImageView(context);
MyPredrawListener listener=new MyPredrawListener(imgWeekView);
imgWeekView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnPreDrawListener(listener);
```

In OnPreDraw function I put test code to see the result graphically, clearing bitmap to gray color and painting yellow circle to bottom right of a view.

[image]